# How can I best prepare for a meeting with HR about a coworkers Passive-Agressive Conflict with me?

Tags: colleagues, bullying, passive-aggressiveness

I work with a male coworker who I'd describe as a passive-aggressive bully. He has angry outbursts daily, several times a day, over every little noise in the office. If another coworker coughs, or talks too loudly, or shuts a desk drawer too loudly, I can expect to hear him mumble angry things under his breath, stomp his feet, slam his mouse, literally SNAP at coworkers or ultimately get up and leave the office in a huff. Several times he has been sent home after altercations.

This all happens from behind his cubicle walls--I'm pretty sure I'm the only one who witnesses this behavior on a day-to-day basis as it is *very* passive aggressive.

He has a history of this behavior. One coworker already quit over his passive aggressive bullying, after HR met with everyone in our office. Another coworker had to move her desk away from him after an altercation. He's been sent home numerous times. He's now bullying the new female coworker who sits adjacent his cubicle who unfortunately has a persistent cough.

To be fair, I don't find his frustrations unfounded at all. The people in our office are largely oblivious and annoying in their habits. I'm conflicted because I've been an ally of sorts with him as we've joked through chat about the annoyances of the office. I realize this was a huge mistake now that I better know his personality.

**The issue is that his angry outbursts are affecting me. I'm starting to feel like I'm in an abusive relationship, even if the anger isn't directed at me. It's making me quite uncomfortable, and creating a very tense work environment.**

He knows this behavior is not okay. At least twice now he's come in the next day following a blow-up, and apologized to me for his behavior.

**I want this behavior to stop.**

How can I best prepare for a meeting with HR about a coworkers Passive-Agressive Conflict with me?

Comment: why is he still there? What makes him so valuable?

Comment: @Kilisi I'd got as far as to say he is not so valuable. But that's not my decision. We work in an institution where I imagine it's very difficult to get fired.

Comment: Do you actually have to work *with* him daily or at least often? Would it be possible to move your desk / sever contact either to get away from him now or in case he lashes out against you if you try to take any action?

Comment: @conflicted - That you can not see his value at all, tells me you are too bias to provide an accurate opinion of the companies opinion of your problem coworker.

Comment: @RichardU your sarcasm aside, my point is: he is repeatedly acting in an abusive manner, then apologizing the day after, as if that vindicates his behavior. Much like an abusive alcoholic or spouse, or, in this case, an abusive rage-a-holic.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings I was asked what makes him *so valuable* that he's still here [implicitly that he hasn't been fired as a result of his behavior]. I didn't say he didn't have any value. I said he's not so valuable that he can bully his coworkers and we all turn a blind eye.

Comment: @conflicted I think if you edited your post to focus on his behavior as opposed to overused buzzwords and hyperbole, you'd get a better response.  **show, don't tell**

Comment: @RichardU Thanks for the sage advice on avoiding tired sarcasm. The post is almost entirely focused on his behavior, not sure if you read it.

Comment: @conflicted yes, I did read it thank you.  Most of us sages are a bit on the sarcastic side, but our advice is sound nonetheless.  Also, for future reference, it you wait at least 24 hours to pick the best answer, you tend to get more responses.  We have plenty of users from all over the world, so you can get some really interesting answers.  But, my previous advice was not just on avoiding sarcasm, but also avoiding down-votes, which can also detract from getting good answers.  Mister Positive's answer is a great one, however.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Should I confront him or contact HR?

If you are unable to **ignore** the culprit....

**First** you should confront him, be direct and try to keep your emotions in check.  **Then** if that fails you go to your *manager*.  Be professional, honest, and factual in both cases.

If all of that fails, think *carefully* about going to HR.  **HR is not your friend**, as Richard U says, they are there to protect the company.

Having said all of that, if all else fails you may be left with no choice but to go to HR, or find another job.

Comment: Stellar answer as usual sir.

Comment: As a person who used to have his personality (though not that extreme) This is 100% the way to go. +1

Comment: So many people tend to forget the power of the cold shoulder.  +1

Comment: This is good advice. Point noted about HR not being my friend, and to add to that their particular uselessness in solving this situation first go-round. Despite @IDrinkandIKnowThings 's odd choice to change the title of my question (humor?), I'm actually not going to talk to HR at all, but confront the coworker and then talk to my manager if need be.

Comment: Hi, @conflicted IdrinkandIknowthings's edit made your question on-topic.  The previous title might have gotten it closed under the reason that we cannot help you make specific choices.  He's very active at our stack, one of the most, in fact. and likes to look out for new users.

Answer (score 1):

"How can I best prepare for the meeting..."

Write down a list of specific facts: things that have happened.  With dates.

In the meeting, enumerate the list.

Say and do nothing else.